# How to add GroundingDino to HuggingFace?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, image-segmentation, huggingface, huggingface-hub

When I attempting to deploy Segment and Track Anything (SAM Track)  (https://huggingface.co/spaces/aikenml/Segment-And-Track-Anything-Model) (SAM Track, https://github.com/z-x-yang/Segment-and-Track-Anything) to HugginFace(HF) Space, I encountered the following error: https://huggingface.co/spaces/aikenml/Segment-And-Track-Anything-Model
[no module named 'groundingdino'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nYdg.png)

This is working locally, and 'groundingdino' is specified in the requirements.txt in HF. However, the error persists on Hugging Face Spaces. How can I resolve this issue?